# How to enable systemd's --user functionality on RedHat via Ansible?

Tags: ansible, daemon, systemd, rhel7

We need to allow a non-root user-account to manipulate *their own services*: start at boot, stop, (re)start, query status... The user will be providing their own `.service` file(s) -- we just need to tell `systemd` to honor those...

I believe, this is accomplished by running `systemd --user`, and we need to do this on scores of RHEL7 machines using Ansible.

Can it be done using the [systemd module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html)? Please, provide an example.

If not, what commands should we use with the shell- or command-modules? Thanks!

Comment: The documentation to which you've linked seems to answer that question already (specifically, the documentation around the `scope` option). What parts of the documentation are unclear?

Comment: Maybe, I just need an example? Could you provide one, @larsks? Make it a proper answer, and I'll gladly accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Starting in this [line](https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-oracledb/blob/3966567ed59faa9b7aa303ebe4dea43943f1ec53/roles/create_db_service/tasks/main.yml#L19) you will find an example.

Comment: @rcastellcastell, there is not a single reference to the `systemd`-module at that link... And it all appears to be about starting a service (Oracle) as root -- not as an ordinary user.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is not about using systemd to create a service, your question is more about giving privileges to a user or group to manage a service. Therefore, you should edit the sudoers file to provide these privileges. I have extracted this example from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-could-we-allow-non-root-users-to-control-a-systemd-service), which hopefully is clear for you.

```
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl stop httpd.service
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl start httpd.service 
%webteam cms051=/usr/bin/systemctl status httpd.service
```

The small value that I can add here is by suggesting that you can automate this configuration using a template to modify the file. Here, I have an example that used to modify sudoers some time ago for other purposes so I think you will be able to create your own template using the example above.

**Template**

```
    {{ xyz_user }} ALL = ({{ oracle_user }}) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**Task**

```
    - name: "Creating sudoers file for {{ xyz_user }} user"
      template:
        src: templates/xyzsudoers.j2
        dest: /etc/sudoers.d/xyzsudoers
        mode: 0440
        validate: '/usr/sbin/visudo -cf %s'
```

Importantly the task I created was based on this amazing [post](https://medium.com/sallesslice-com/visudo-with-ansible-746f83547bb3)

Comment: Thanks. This method allows a user to manipulate certain -- predetermined -- set of services as root (using `sudo`). What I was looking for was give a user the ability to manipulate _any_ service of their own -- full list not known in advance. I already learned, how to do it on RHEL-based systems and will be answering my own question shortly.